# java.lang.VerifyError: class com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.ser.ScalaIteratorSerializer overrides final method withResolved

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I get the following error stack trace when initializing my Java program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.ser.ScalaIteratorSerializer overrides final method withResolved.(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/BeanProperty;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/TypeSerializer;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/AsArraySerializerBase;
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.ser.IteratorSerializerModule$class.$init$(IteratorSerializerModule.scala:70)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.<init>(DefaultScalaModule.scala:19)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule$.<init>(DefaultScalaModule.scala:35)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule$.<clinit>(DefaultScalaModule.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<init>(RDDOperationScope.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<clinit>(RDDOperationScope.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:714)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.hadoopRDD(SparkContext.scala:991)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JSONRelation.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$json$JSONRelation$$createBaseRdd(JSONRelation.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JSONRelation$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(JSONRelation.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JSONRelation$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(JSONRelation.scala:115)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JSONRelation$$anonfun$4.apply(JSONRelation.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JSONRelation$$anonfun$4.apply(JSONRelation.scala:109)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JSONRelation.dataSchema$lzycompute(JSONRelation.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JSONRelation.dataSchema(JSONRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.HadoopFsRelation.schema$lzycompute(interfaces.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.HadoopFsRelation.schema(interfaces.scala:635)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.LogicalRelation.<init>(LogicalRelation.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:244)
    at org.test.loader.Loader.readJsonFile(Loader.java:73)
    at org.test.loader.Loader.run(Loader.java:50)
    at org.test.loader.LoadCatalogue.main(LoadCatalogue.java:22)
```

Cannot understand what is the reason of this error. Could it related to the conflict between the libraries that I use in the Maven project?

Just in case I provide the file `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spark.version>1.6.1</spark.version>
        <es.version>2.2.0</es.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
                <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.spullara.mustache.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>${es.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
        <artifactId>jena-tdb</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.2</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: You're using 1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT as spring boot version. That is certainly not a good thing for dependency stability. Is there any reason for that? 1.4.5 is for instance released.

Comment: @Tome: I switched to `1.4.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`, but the error is the same.

Comment: So there is clearly a dependency conflict. See for instance here for hints: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/issues/214

Comment: @Tome: Thanks. I added these two dependencies in pom.xml and it solved the issue: `<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: @Dinosaurius solution works for scala 2.11 as well just change to jackson-module-scala_2.11.

Answer (score 7):

Add the following dependencies will resolve the issue.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Which `xml` file does this go in?